# How to use grep with regex to find all the files containing a 'String'?

Tags: linux, unix

I am using SSH secure shell in Unix, I want to search file with some 'TEXT' or string
and that string is like 'PACKAGE', followed by '%PA%EVENTS%'('PA_PACKAGE %PA%EVENTS%')
this % i am assuming as in SQL*PLUS, means i a string PA can occur any where before EVENTS
and EVENTS can occur any where after PA,
I want to search those file which this REGEX matches.

Comment: Could you give some sample of lines?

Comment: but there is a space btween PACKAGE and '%PA%EVENTS%..

Answer (score 1):

I ma not sure exactly what you are hoping to match, but the following will print out the **lines** that contain the text "*PACKAGE*" followed but zero or more characters and then the  text "*EVENTS*", from all the files in the current directory.

```
grep "PACKAGE.*EVENTS" *
```

Please give some more examples of what you want, so I can be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `egrep -e "PACKAGE PA*EVENTS" file`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l "PACKAGE*EVENTS" *
```

recursive:

```
grep -Rl "PACKAGE*EVENTS" *
```

Comment: "E*E" means two or more Es, your wan't "E.*E" meaning E + any number of any character + another E. See Beano's example.